# waveform code .. ..I do need help...please

Tags: java

Can you please , explain to me (in words) what this code does?
thank you

My concerns are actually these two parts :
1)

```
double y_new = (double) (h * (128 - my_byte) / 256);
lines.add(new Line2D.Double(x, y_last, x, y_new));
y_last = y_new;
```

2) the for loop , I dont'understand...
   what's 32768 ? 
   my_byte?

```
        int numChannels = format.getChannels();
        for (double x = 0; x < w && audioData != null; x++) {

        int idx = (int) (frames_per_pixel * numChannels * x);
        // se a 8 bit è immediato
        if (format.getSampleSizeInBits() == 8) {
            my_byte = (byte) audioData[idx];
        } else {
            my_byte = (byte) (128 * audioData[idx] / 32768);
```

Here's the code . It was taken from here :
http://www.koders.com/java/fid3508156A13C80A263E7CE65C4C9D6F5D8651AF5D.aspx?s=%22David+Anderson%22
(class Sampling Graph)

```
        int frames_per_pixel = audioBytes.size() / format.getFrameSize() / w;
        byte my_byte = 0;
        double y_last = 0;
        int numChannels = format.getChannels();
        for (double x = 0; x < w && audioData != null; x++) {
        // scegli quale byte visualizzare
        int idx = (int) (frames_per_pixel * numChannels * x);
        // se a 8 bit è immediato
        if (format.getSampleSizeInBits() == 8) {
            my_byte = (byte) audioData[idx];
        } else {

            my_byte = (byte) (128 * audioData[idx] / 32768);
        }

        double y_new = (double) (h * (128 - my_byte) / 256);
        lines.add(new Line2D.Double(x, y_last, x, y_new));
        y_last = y_new;
        }

        repaint();
```

Comment: Could you please edit the title of your question in a more meaningful one? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=32768+in+hex

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it helps, but

```
128 * someInt / 32768
```

is the same as

```
someInt << 7 >> 15
```

Answer (score 0):

You should at the first place learn how a sound file is organized. But anyway..

```
double y_new = (double) (h * (128 - my_byte) / 256);
        lines.add(new Line2D.Double(x, y_last, x, y_new));
        y_last = y_new;
```

The Y positions of the lines that this example draws are representing the sample values of the sound file. As you may know one sample can be 8/16/32...bit. In this exaple they scale all bit values down to 8 (1 byte). The ne Y will have its center in the screen mid position (its a signed sound file). h is the screen hight-we want to scale it as if 127 is the screen top and -127 the screen lower pixel.

2) 32768 is the max value for a signed 16 bit integer. Thus, the max sample value for a 16 bit sound file. myByte: A sound file is saved as a byte stream. So evan if you use 16bit samples, you will have to create your integer (16bit, 32bin in Java) from the 2 bytes from the screen. In this example they work only with 8bit sample data, so if this example reads a 16bit sound file it will convert the sample values to 8 bit in this line:

```
 my_byte = (byte) (128 * audioData[idx] / 32768);
```

So my byte holds the sample value of frame "idx".

Answer (score 0):

```
double y_new = (double) (h * (128 - my_byte) / 256);
```

This line of code is part of a method to plot a sequence of bytes on a 'windows' (rectangle, coordinate system, as you like)

```
h       := the height of the drawable area in pixel
my_byte := a byte [-128,127] (a 8 bit sample from an audio file?)
```

`(128 - my_byte)` converts the input `[-128,127]` to `[256, 1]`. Division by 256 transforms this range to `[1, 1/256]` and multiplying with the height `h` results in the expected mapping from `[-128,127]` --> `[~0,h]`

The following to lines are for drawing a line from the point representing the previous byte to the actual point. The actual point will then become the previous point for the next iteration.

---

```
my_byte = (byte) (128 * audioData[idx] / 32768);
```

This line of code is execute if the sample size is 16Bit. But we need an 8Bit value just for the plotting. An `int` in Java is 32 Bit, we have a 16 Bit sample, so the upper 16 Bit are 0, the lower 16 Bit store the audio sample value. The algorithm now shifts the value 7 positions to the left, then 15 to the right:

```
   00000000 00000000 11111111 11111111 
-> 00000000 01111111 11111111 10000000  // * 128,   << 7
-> 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111  // : 32768, >> 15
```

Honestly, i do not know why the author didn't just divide by 256 once, that should give the same result.

But anyway - the result is a byte that represents the eight most significant bits of the sample. Pretty inaccurate, by the way, because if you have a very quiete 16 bit recording you'll see nothing on the wave panel.